# Can we write any objects before the subject?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

In the given sentence

> Für das bin ich zuständig.

is this sentence correct? I am skeptical because the object comes before the subject.

Answer (score 3):

The word order is fine, yes. "Dafür" would be used instead of "für das", though, regardless of the position.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is one of the possible word orderings in German. With it, you put the focus to the object. Compare:

> Ich bin zuständig für das

means *"I am responsible for that"*. While

> Für das bin ich zuständing

means *"This is for what I am responsible"*.